# Spark Streaming Outputting An Event for Every Input Event

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I see that Spark Streaming takes events in minibatches, and produces otuput for each minibatch.

I am particulary interested in updateStateByKey.

Say I want to compute the running sum for a streaming sequence of integers.

With minibatches and updateStateByKey I can get the sampled sum - but what if I want there to be exactly one output event for every input event. Is this possible with Spark Streaming?

Comment: Spark Streaming *processes* streams in mini-batches, but the output produced is a result of operations on the individual data. So 1 `event in` => 1 `event out` is possible. Also, 1 -> n (stream enrichment) and n -> 1 (aggregation) are possible.